# Handle open multiple URLs in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, appdelegate, facebook-sdk-3.0

I have the following code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation
{

    return [Braintree handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];

}
```

but Facebook SDK integration requires me to do that:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
  // attempt to extract a token from the url
  return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];
}
```

How do I handle opening of the necessary application?

Answer (score 6):

Use the response from the method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation
{
  if ([FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication])
    return YES;
  return [Braintree handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];
}
```